# Вложенные urlpatterns в Django

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, django, чпу

Необходимо реализовать `urlpatterns`, с глубокой вложенностью, с тем учётом, что принимаемые аргументы являются одинаковыми.

Как вариант, такой тип url'ов может применяться, например, для фильтрации товаров в интернет магазине.

Пример такого урла: `tsvet-cherniy`, или `tsvet-cherniy-zeleniy`

Вот часть регулярного выражения, которое решает поставленную задачу: `((?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w/-]+)))*/$`

И если внутри `views` парсить такой урл `tsvet-cherniy-zeleniy`:

```
print(self.kwargs['filter_code'])
print(self.kwargs['filter_name'])
```

то результат будет ожидаемым:

```
tsvet
cherniy-zeleniy
```

И это именно то, что нужно.

Но проблема появляется тогда, когда появляется следующая вложенность. Например, возьмём такой урл:

```
tsvet-cherniy-zeleniy/razmer-bolshoy
```

И при попытке его распрасить как показано выше, результат будет таким:

```
tsvet
cherniy-zeleniy/razmer-bolshoy
```

А это уже совсем не тот результат, который ожидается. 
Возникает он по вполне понятной причине, но как этого избежать?

**На ум приходит несколько вариантов:**

1. Использовать такую структуру `urlpatterns` и добавить ещё по 2 аргумента на каждую вложенность:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [

   url(r'^(?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w-]+))/$',
       self.filter_view.as_view(), name='filter'),

   url(r'^(?P<filter_code>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name>[\w-]+))/(?P<filter_code_two>[\w]+)(-(?P<filter_name_two>[\w-]+))/$',
       self.filter_view.as_view(), name='filter'),    ]
   ```

Но этот вариант мне не очень нравится, из-за того что дублируется код, и усложняется логика во `view`, а так же потому, что не известно заранее, сколько максимум возможно вложенностей.

1. Использовать не 2 аргумента (`<filter_code>` и `<filter_name>`), а один, и уже во `view` его разделять при помощи `split('-')`, где `[0]` - будет является эквивалентом `<filter_code>`, а все последующие - `<filter_name>`. Вложенности же разделять при помощи `split('/')`.

Но это не явное решение, такой код будет плохо пахнуть.

3. Крайний случай - отказаться от `regex` и просто парсить `GET`, т.е. делать как это делают в большинстве случаев.

Обычно такая строка выглядит так `?tsvet=[zeleniy,krasniy,siniy]`, но в моём случае, важно, чтобы строка была ЧПУ.

**Так же, крайне важно, чтобы была сохранена последовательность**

Comment: Я использую regexp соответствующей вложенности. Ваш первый вариант. Зачем бояться сложностей во view? Вы получаете очень предсказуемые url, игра стоит свеч.

Comment: Получится много if self.kwargs[...], если будет 5 вложенностей, то это будет не опрятный код.

Comment: Зачем self.args, можно в принципе скомбинировать с while () и парсить аргументы filter_codes, filter_names. Да, и с точки зрения поисковых систем вроде более красивыми считаются Url через косую черту, без "?". Впихивайте в два поля много параметров например через "-", разделяйте их split и по словарям/ моделям берите id :)